# Does a geometry exist where the circumference can be the square of the radius, $C = R^2$?

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

In normal, Euclidean space, the circumference of a circle is a linear function of the radius:
$$f(R) = 2 \pi R$$Does a geometry exist where the locus of points equidistant from a common point, $P_0$, such that the the distance around the surface (e.g. circumference in Euclidean space) is a function of the square of the radius (that is, the distance from $P_0$ to the surface) such that:$$f(R)=R^2$$
Is there anything to prevent me from hypothesizing such a shape?

Comment: Interesting idea. Seems improbable to me since your geometry must in some sense  be (almost) a two dimensional manifold in order for "circumference" to make sense.

Comment: The context is something like a four-dimensional hypersphere, though I'm not sure it's, strictly speaking, a 'sphere'.  So when I say 'circumference', I'm just talking about the distance you would walk (in one of the dimensions on the surface of this object) before you ended up back where you started.

Comment: Do you mean this shall hold for any circle center in the surface (or in the space)? Or just one particular "common point" inside the surface?

Comment: I hesitate to use the term 'circle' or 'sphere' as it would immediately suggest a dependency on $pi$.  I'm wondering, if we relieve ourselves of Euclidean constrictions, do I have permission to imagine (hypothesis) a shape where every point on the surface of this shape is the same distance from a common center, $P_0$, but if I walk around the surface of the object, I'll measure the square of the distance to $P_0$.

Comment: As an example, in the hyperbolic plane, the circumference of a circle grows exponentially with the radius. The formula is $$C = 2\pi\sinh r.$$

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Thank you.  Is it possible to extend that basic idea beyond conical sections?  More importantly, can I hypothesis a shape like this?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "beyond conical sections"? The problem with the formula $C(r)=r^2$ is that it is already wrong for infinitesimal values of $r$. This is what the current answer by Ivo Terek and the comments to it are about. If you compare to the formula $C(r)=2\pi\sinh r$ of my comment above, this formula agrees with $C(r)\approx 2\pi r$ for $r$ infinitesimally small. For a regular surface, everything must become Euclidean for very small circles. Except if you have some kind of cusp or apex there (singularity, not smooth/regular).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Sorry, I didn't read your previous comment closely enough.  I was thinking of cross-sections of a sphere which grow as $$C = 2 \pi R sin \theta$$

Comment: Here's an additional thought.  Let's say the radius, $y$ is of unit $t$.  My data tells me that the circumference (that is, the distance around this shape), is $y^2$ which means the units of this space is $t^2$.  It occurs to me that we're not dealing with the same dimensions.  Can you create a shape and measure the curvature of something composed of $t$ and $t^2$?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the answer is no in dimension $2$, at least. By [Bertrand-Diquet-Puiseux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%E2%80%93Diquet%E2%80%93Puiseux_theorem), the Gaussian curvature at the center of the circle would have to be $+\infty$. If I recall correctly, there are analogues of this formula for higher dimensions using the Ricci curvature, but I don't have any reference for it now.

Comment: (By "circle" I mean "geodesic circle", of course)

Comment: Could we have $C(r)=2\pi r + r^2$ instead since it is Euclidean in the limit $r$ close to zero? Eventually this function looks like $r^2$ of course.

Comment: The problem is one for four dimensions, at least, projected ultimately on three dimensions.

Comment: It might be possible. Equip an open set of $\Bbb R^2$ with the metric $ds^2 = dx^2 + G(x,y) dy^2$, where $G>0$ outside $(0,0)$, with $\sqrt{G(0,y)} = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} (\sqrt{G})_x(x,y) = 1$. Then if $C_R$ denotes the geodesic circle centered in the origin with radius $R$, one can prove that $$L(C_R) = 2\pi\left(R - K_0\frac{R^3}{6}+o(R^3)\right),$$where $K_0$ is the Gaussian curvature of the metric at the origin (in the limit). Maybe one can try to solve for $G$ setting that last expression equal to $R^2$.

Comment: In an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, if we pick a 2-dimensional "section" (like a 2-dimensional linear subspace of the tangent fiber at the center point), then taking circles in that 2-dimensional "sheet" inside the manifold, and using the same limit as in your link, ought to give the sectional curvature.

Comment: Of course, if the center point is not in a place where the surface is "smooth", the Bertrand–Diquet–Puiseux need not be a problem. For example, if we take the center point as the __apex__ of a classical cone, then I guess $C(r) = ar$ for some coefficient $a<2\pi$. Maybe it is possible to make a saddle-point like "apex" such that the formula $C(r)=r^2$ holds.

Comment: @IvoTerek - if the answer $L(C_R) = ...$ is feasible, could you make it into an answer so people can vote on whether it's more correct than your original 'no' answer?  And does this geometry have a name?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - The 'center' of this configuration, dimensionally speaking, not connected to the surface except by the fact that every point on the surface is equidistant (that is, at a distance of R) from that point.