# Can you mix units of $t$ and $t^2$ when constructing a shape?

Tags: geometry, dimension-theory-analysis, dimensional-analysis

Let's say I have a length (possibly a radius), we'll call it $y$ and is of unit $t$. My data suggests to me that the distance around this shape (possibly a circumference), is $y^2$, which means the units of this space is $t^2$. Is it possible that the data suggests an underlying geometry? Can you create a shape and measure the curvature of something composed of $t$ and $t^2$?

Comment: Do you mean that if you make a copy of this shape exactly twice as large in "radius", you get a "circumference" four times larger than before? That would suggest that the "circumference" actually has area rather than length. You might get a useful answer if you edited the question to be much clearer about exactly what you are doing, for example what exactly is the "shape" you are dealing with.

Comment: @DavidK - I don't know what shape I'm dealing with, I don't even know if it qualifies as a shape.  That's my question.  My data tells me there's a relation between a given length in one dimension (t = time) and the amount of space in another dimension ($t^2$ = space).  Is it possible to have an underlying geometry to this configuration or is it impossible to construct a shape from $apples$ and $apples^2$?

Comment: It seems to me as if this question is from the same problem as your older question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587946/does-a-geometry-exist-where-the-circumference-can-be-the-square-of-the-radius It might be helpful if you edited this positng  to show us the problem you started with that led you to this one. Perhaps you are asking an x-y question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @EthanBolker - I had considered that, but I don't want to prejudice of confuse this question with the direction the other question went.  It's a simple enough question, can you create a geometry from $apples$ and $apples^2$ (I know $apples^2$ looks like an area, but it acts like a distance when we measure it)?

Comment: Define "a geometry".

Comment: In non-Euclidean geometries it is possible that the dimensions of a shape do not scale up equally, that is, you could have a "circumference" that grows either faster or slower than the "radius." But I don't think it makes any sense even then to use units of area to measure a length, so I suspect you are not asking the question you actually need to ask. Your decision to hold back information (here and in the earlier problem) may preclude giving any useful answer.

Comment: @DavidK - The magnitude of SNe Ia (supernovae) match a quadratic law of expansion much better than FLRW.  That indicates that space grows as a function of the square of time.  I'm looking for a geometry to support what I've found in my data.  When I hypothesis that $y = t^2$ (where y is in units of $t^2$), I'm able to explain the expansion of space without needing some hypothetical energy or anti-gravity.  I'm looking to explain Dark Energy with geometry.

Comment: @DavidK - Additionally, we can't measure $t^2$, so I additionally posit that what we're able to measure is space, but that space is related to time by $x = \phi t^2$ where $\phi$ is some constant with units of $km$ $s^{-2}$.

Comment: @DavidK - And this is the point in the conversation where I typically lose people.

Comment: Have you tried asking in Physics SE? They're better with units (and space stuff) over there. I can also vote to migrate this if you add more background to the question.

Comment: The way I understand your question now: is there an object (more specifically probably a manifold) where a linear increase in one dimension (to be equated with time) corresponds to a quadratic increase in (3?) other dimensions (considered space)? And yes, of course you can have such an object, particularly if you allow for a factor of $\phi$ to make units match and relate scales in different dimensions. For example the quartic surface $x^2+y^2+z^2-\phi^2t^4=0$ would satisfy this. Is this what you are asking, or are there any additional constraints not satisfied by this?

Comment: @Dylan - Cosmologists are absolutely convinced that Dark Energy causes the expansion of space.  They're not sure what it is, but they're sure it's something.  Have you ever tried to change the mind of an intelligent person who's absolutely convinced they know something that isn't true?  If I can find a geometric principle here, I might have a chance, but I'm sure the mathematicians hold the key.

Comment: @MvG - Yes!  I've sketched that out that metric, but I wasn't sure it was possible!  Is this a shape and, if so, does it have a name?

Comment: I'm more inclined to trust physicists who know what they're doing. That's just my suggestion.

Comment: @Dylan - Why would you trust someone who's theory misses the observation by 95%?  Would you trust a biologists that told you they have a model for a closed ecosystem but they can't account for 95% of the apex predators?

Comment: Yes $x^2+y^2+z^2-\phi^2t^4=0$ is a 4d “shape”. You can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2-z%5E4%3D0) to obtain a plot of the 3d counterpart. If you click on the “Open code” link you even get a version you can rotate using your mouse. I'm no expert in the classification of higher-dimensional quartics, but rephrasing the question and adding the algebraic-geometry tag might attract someone who does know a more specific name for this.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury I have a feeling you're just asking this to feel superior and be condescending to physicists. But I don't want to start anything.

Comment: Note that the distance traveled under constant acceleration $g$ for time $t$ starting from rest is $\frac12gt^2,$ in units of distance (not squared). This has little to do with supernovae, but it is another example of something growing quadratically with respect to time.

Comment: I would call $x^2+y^2+z^2-\phi^2t^4=0$ a paraboloid (because it's a 4-D analogue of a 3-D paraboloid). Now, supposing you are able to describe precisely the geometry of the expansion of space, you might try to describe the mechanism that causes it to expand. (But describe it to someone who knows enough about dark energy to say whether a different explanation is better or worse; I'm not that person, and I suspect this is not the best place to find such a person.)

Comment: @DavidK - The interpretation is that every point in space has an intrinsic acceleration associated with it of $a_0 = \phi t^2 dt = 2 \phi$.  This intrinsic acceleration ends up acting exactly like Dark Matter, but you're right, that's a discussion for a different place.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MvG - I believe you've got it.  If you want to make it into an answer, I can vote it up and mark it.

Comment: @DavidK: A paraboloid is a quadric (degree $2$), not a quartic (degree $4$) as the surface discussed here (due to the $t^4$ term). So I have my doubts about that. I would call it paraboloid if it were $x^2+y^2+z^2-\phi t$, i.e. if the degree of $t$ were *half* that of the spatial dimensions, instead of *twice* that.

Comment: @MvG Good point. The paraboloid I would usually think of is a parabola rotated around its own axis; this surface is analogous to a parabola rotated around at line tangent to its apex.

Comment: Is it fair to describe this as a metric: $ds^2=\phi^2dt^4-d\Sigma^2$ where $\Sigma$ ranges over 3-dimensional space (if there's a better notation, please provide it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing $t$ and $t^2$ directly has problems since the units don't match. In a comment you indicated a correction factor $\phi$ in front of the quadratic term $t^2$, and with that you can certainly express things which correlate linear grow in one direction with quadratic grow in another direction.

From the comments I learned that you essentially want space ($x,y,z$) to grow quadratically with time ($t$). So you want something like

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\phi t^2$$

or expressed as a polynomial

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-\phi^2t^4=0$$

This is an [algebraic variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety), and as the highest degree is $4$, it's a [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_surface). It has some specific properties with regards to the symmetry and degrees of the spatial dimensions, so there may well be a more specific name for this, but I don't know it.

You can [have Wolfram Alpha plot $x^2+y^2-z^4=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2-z%5E4%3D0) for an idea of what the 3d counterpart of this 4d surface looks like. If you click on the link “Open code” you get a version where you can rotate the plot by mouse, and adjust the portion of space to view.

Regarding your intended physical interpretation, note that the existence of a mathematical description does not explain its derivation from the laws of physics. So if you state that the universe for some reason follows a structure such as this, then I expect the typical reaction to be one of “fine, but *why*?” That question would be better suited for the physics stack exchange, though.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer has been very helpful.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: I'm confused.  When Eratosthenes hypothesized that the world was round, did anyone ask 'why'?  Is 'why' a prerequisite to a disprovable hypothesis?

Comment: @Mike: Not sure how advanced the scientific method was at Eratosthenes' time, but when Kepler described the observed movement of the planets, that left the *why* open, until Newton could explain that with a simple law of nature. I would expect that these days, the scientific community would not be satisfied with a Kepler-style description, and would expect a Newton-style explanation. Mainly because that allows making a wider range of deductions not already covered by observations. Not to say that describing an observation is not a relevant achievement in its own right, it's just not complete.

Comment: Can you tell me why gravity works?  Didn't Newton just kick the can down the road a little further :)
I've got a follow-up question at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590224/what-is-the-curvature-of-this-metric.  If I'm right, then this will have a curvature of 0 for a large t, but it's a little beyond my skills at the moment.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury Newton did not kick the can further down the line. He reasoned logically why gravity worked the way it did and provided a model which not on fit the available data but would predict the outcome of future empirical testing. Furthermore despite Newtonian physics proving inaccurate the expectation of modern theories of gravitation is that they would become approximately Newtonian under the right conditions. This is a higher standard than merely making up whatever fits the data, it must also be resilient to new measurements and result in empirically verifiable claims.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - You are reacting out of emotion rather than an understanding of physics. No one, to this day, knows why gravity works: it's an empirical law - same kind of law as Kepler's.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury You're just arguing the semantics of "why" and that's metaphysics, not physics. Physics, like all the sciences, is a social discipline. In the end you can propose any theory you want but that's a lot different than having anyone listen. One of the reasons people listened to Newton and it had a lot to do with his explanation of why gravity works the way it does. I think you'll find your thoughts will be held to a similar standard if you intend to sway minds.