# What is the curvature of this metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

This is a follow up to a question about a [four dimensional geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589558/can-you-mix-units-of-t-and-t2-when-constructing-a-shape/2590452?noredirect=1#comment5348383_2590452) that's suggested by data I've collected.

If I have a surface defined by:$$ds^2=-(\phi^2t^2)dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$where $\phi$ is a constant with units of $km$ $s^{-2}$, t is time ($s$), x, y and z are spatial coordiantes (in $km$), how would I calculate the curvature of the spatial surface?

Is the curvature zero (that is, does this metric describe perfectly flat space)?

Comment: I don't understand what your formula is supposed to mean. Usually, the notation $ds^2$ stands for a Riemannian metric, that is, a positive definite symmetric $2$-tensor field. But $dt^4$ is a $4$-tensor, so it doesn't make sense to add it to a bunch of $2$-tensors. And I have no idea how that formula is supposed to define a surface.

Comment: @JackLee - So sorry, I've updated the question to include the units of the constant.  Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: It still doesn't make mathematical sense, for the same reason I mentioned above. Maybe it would help if you explain exactly how this equation is supposed to define a surface.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? The $\phi^2dt^4$ expression is a 2-tensors (that is, it has units of $km^2$, like the rest of the equation.)

Comment: You should reference [the question which lead to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2589558/35416). Having that context makes answering this question (or pointing out mistakes in the way you formulated it) more likely.

Comment: @MvG - Thanks.  I've updated the main text to give some context.

Comment: In my answer to the previous question, I had suggested a surface defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2-\phi^2t^4=0$. And I had assumed you had something like the Euclidean metric of the containing space for this. I consider it highly likely there is a mistake how you turned that surface definition into a metric definition. And I realize that a Euclidean metric over a space-time continuum is far from an obvious concept, so things probably aren't as simple as this. I have no experience how curvature in spacetime constructs is usually measured.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explain exactly what you think $dt^4$ means mathematically.